# Defining a method that uses an out-of-scope variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, closures

I want to make a Test::Unit test_helper method that I can call to wipe a bunch of tables after the tests execute. Here's the general idea I have:

```
def self.wipe_models(*models)
  def teardown
    models.each do |model|
      model = model.to_s.camelize.constantize
      model.connection.execute "delete from #{model.table_name}"
    end
  end
end
```

However, when `teardown` runs, I get:

> undefined local variable or method `models'

To me it looks like the "def" block doesn't obey usual rules for closures; I can't access variables defined outside of its scope.

So, how do I access a variable that's defined outside of a "def" method declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as a closure with `define_method`:

```
def self.wipe_models(*models)
  define_method(:teardown) do
    models.each do |model|
      model = model.to_s.camelize.constantize
      model.connection.execute "delete from #{model.table_name}"
    end
  end
end
```

Now the method body is a block and can access `models`.

Answer (score 4):

Method definitions are not closures in Ruby. The `class`, `module`, `def`, and `end` keywords are all scope gates. In order to maintain scope across a scope gate you have to pass a block; blocks are closures and thus run in the scope in which they were defined.

```
def foo
  # since we're in a different scope than the one the block is defined in,
  # setting x here will not affect the result of the yield
  x = 900
  puts yield  #=> outputs "16"
end

# x and the block passed to Proc.new have the same scope
x = 4
square_x = Proc.new { x * x }


foo(&square_x)
```

Comment: ...which, unfortunately, I can't do, since the call to teardown isn't under my control. :-\ I was afraid of this, but thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class instance variable:

```
cattr_accessor :models_to_wipe

def self.wipe_models(*models)
  self.models_to_wipe = models
end

def teardown
  self.class.models_to_wipe.each do |model|
    model = model.to_s.camelize.constantize
    model.connection.execute "delete from #{model.table_name}"
  end
end
```